# jQuery using on and bind in the same call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran into this code and am not sure how it works:

```
options.on('change', this._onBundleOptionChanged.bind(this));
```

this._onBundleOptionChanged is simply a function that takes one paramter, event:

```
_onBundleOptionChanged: function onBundleOptionChanged(event) {
```

jQuery version is 1.12.4.

the bind call returns function bound() whatever that means and if bind is passed a single parameter it has to be an object the documentation says "An object containing one or more DOM event types and functions to execute for them." here: http://api.jquery.com/bind/

So as I understand what it accomplishes, calling the _onBundleOptionChanged method when a select dropdown is changed.

What I don't understand is how, or why anyone would program it this way.

Comment: It depends more on the code around `options.on("change")`.  Using `bind(this)` will make `this` mean the same thing inside `onBundleOptionChanged` as it does outside it (where the event handler is assigned).  There could be lots of reasons for doing this, as well as it simply being unnecessary.  Have a look how `this` is used inside the event handler - it should give you some clue as to why.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Isn't bind a deprecated use of on that just references on?  Or is there another method called bind other than the jquery one?  this points to the object that _onBundleOptionChanged belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not jQuery's `bind`.

It is `function.prototype.bind` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

It is changing the context of the callback function to the be the same as when this statement is executed. This can be very useful.

> In most cases, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the `bind` method to set the value of a function's `this` regardless of how it's called, and ES2015 introduced arrow functions which don't provide their own `this` binding (it retains the `this` value of the enclosing lexical context).

See:

[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this